# Is reaping off a correct word

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

**This Company is reaping us off**. Is that a correct sentence? I am not sure what that means
But I feel that it means that the company is taking a lot of work and value
out of the employees. Although it makes some sense I couldn't find it online in any
dictionary

Comment: The word you want is *ripping* (as in [ripping off](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rip-off)) not *reaping*.  If your native language doesn't include both /ɪ/ and /i/, you may not be able to hear a difference in the pronunciation of those two words.  To a native English speaker, they are very different.

Comment: Almost certainly a mishearing of [ripping off](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rip-off). Nobody says 'reap' or 'reaping' off. 'Rip off: 2.  US to cheat, exploit, or take advantage of'.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about a word which was not transcribed correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Reaping us off* isn't an idiom I've ever heard of; I can think of a couple of possibilities, though.

It could be a mondegreen of *Ripping us off*. To rip someone off means to steal from someone, cheat them, overcharge them, or otherwise take advantage of them. Examples:

> "The restaurant charged us for the soup, even though we never got it. What a rip off!"

> "You want to charge us triple for bottled water? You're ripping us off!"

*The company is ripping us off* would mean that the company is in some way dealing unfairly with employees. Perhaps not paying them for overtime, or expecting them to pay for their own office supplies.

If it's not "ripping" but really is "reaping", that would imply that employees are being killed off - or, more likely, that a number of employees have been fired or pushed to quit. It draws on the image of death as the Grim Reaper, harvesting the dead with a scythe.

Of the two, I think that the misheard "ripping us off" is the most likely.

Comment: +1 for the mondegreen.